# R - create new column in data frame based on conditional

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I need to create a column in a data frame with a string of yrs that will identify each yr as `"leap"` or `"reg"` (regular) automatically.

This is what I have thus far:

**Delimit the time period**

```
year<-(2009:2017)
```

**Create a data frame with a single column for that time period**

```
prd_df<-data.frame(year)
```

**Create an empty column where `"leap"` and `"reg"` yrs will be identified**

```
prd_df["leap"]<-NA
```

**Base identification with a conditional loop**

```
for(i in 1:length(prd_df$year)){
  if((prd_df$year[i]%%4==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%100!=0)){
    prd_df$leap<-'leap'
  }else if((prd_df$year[i]%%4==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%100==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%400==0)){
    prd_df$leap<-'leap' 
  }else{
    prd_df$leap<-'reg'
  }
}
```

**Create a table from the resulting data frame.**

```
write.table(prd_df,
          file = "prd.csv",
          row.names = F, col.names = T,
          sep = "\t")
```

This is what I get:

```
"year"  "leap"
2009    "reg"
2010    "reg"
2011    "reg"
2012    "reg"
2013    "reg"
2014    "reg"
2015    "reg"
2016    "reg"
2017    "reg"
```

In the example above, 2012 and 2016 should be identified as `"leap"` in the second column, but it is not working. The conditional has worked fine before as part of other codes but I can't get it to work now. May it not be recognized `prd_df$year` as numeric?

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code , You missed a `[i]`, when assign the new value to column `leaf`

```
 year<-(2009:2017)
    prd_df<-data.frame(year)
    prd_df["leap"]<-NA

    for(i in 1:length(prd_df$year)){
        if((prd_df$year[i]%%4==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%100!=0)){
            prd_df$leap[i]<-'leap'#add [i] here
        }
        else if((prd_df$year[i]%%4==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%100==0)&(prd_df$year[i]%%400==0)){
            prd_df$leap[i]<-'leap' #add [i] here
        }else{
            prd_df$leap[i]<-'reg'#add [i] here
        }
    }


prd_df
  year leap
1 2009  reg
2 2010  reg
3 2011  reg
4 2012 leap
5 2013  reg
6 2014  reg
7 2015  reg
8 2016 leap
9 2017  reg
```

`ifelse` multiple conditions

```
with(prd_df, ifelse(year %%4== 0 & year %%100 !=0, "leap", ifelse(year %%4== 0 & year %%100 !=0&year%%400==0,"leap","reg")))
[1] "reg"  "reg"  "reg"  "leap" "reg"  "reg"  "reg"  "leap" "reg"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Wen. One silly question: how do you get to print the results without quotes? I am new to R (programming in general) and learning as I go...

Comment: @EBB now you have 15 reputation , you can upvote those answers

Answer (score 2):

We can use an `ifelse`

```
prd_df$leap <- with(prd_df, ifelse(year %%4== 0 & year %%100 !=0, "leap", "reg"))
prd_df$leap
#[1] "reg"  "reg"  "reg"  "leap" "reg"  "reg"  "reg"  "leap" "reg"
```

---

Or with `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
prd_df %>%
       mutate(leap = case_when(year %%4 == 0 & year %% 100 !=0 ~ "leap", 
                               TRUE ~"reg"))
#   year leap
#1 2009  reg
#2 2010  reg
#3 2011  reg
#4 2012 leap
#5 2013  reg
#6 2014  reg
#7 2015  reg
#8 2016 leap
#9 2017  reg
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Can I use several conditionals with ifelse? I thought it just allowed one.

Comment: @EBB Yes, you can have nested `ifelse` or multiple conditionals in `case_when`.  Compared to `if/else`, the `ifelse` is vectorized and could be faster

Answer (score 1):

Try to search lubridate package - I think there should be function to check if year is leap.
And for conditions use mutate with case_when from dplyr package.

Whole code should be no longer than 5 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

year_df <- data_frame(year = 1999:2017)

year_df <- year_df %>%
    mutate(leap = ifelse(leap_year(.$year), "leap", "reg"))
```